# Plotting dates with Pandas Matplotlib - random (apparently) years

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a simple .csv file downloaded from Yahoo-finance ([file example here](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/0P0000UL8U.L?period1=962323200&period2=1595116800&interval=1d&events=history)), but I cannot understand why the years appear as (apparently) random numbers. Please see image below: [image]

Another thing that I would like to do is to remove the x axis from the top graph (since the same axis is already in the bottom plot) but I would like to keep the dashed grid. I tired to use `ax[0].set_xticklabels([])`, but it didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MonthLocator, YearLocator


#LOAD DATA
df_name = "0P0000UL8U.L.csv"
col_list = ["Date", "Adj Close"] #list of column to import
df = pd.read_csv(df_name, header=0, usecols=col_list, na_values=['null'], thousands=r',', parse_dates=["Date"], dayfirst=True)
df = df.dropna() #Drop the rows where at least one element is missing.
df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
df.index = [pd.to_datetime(date).date() for date in df.index] #convert index to datetime.date, not datetime.datetime.
print("Opening df:\n", df)
print("\nLength of df: ", len(df.index))


#PLOT DATA
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(11,5))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.25, hspace=0.8) #Adjust space between graphs

df[["Adj Close"]].plot(ax=ax[0], kind="line", style="-", color="blue", stacked=False, rot=90)
ax[0].set_axisbelow(True)  # To put plot grid below plots
ax[0].yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax[0].xaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())  # specify a MonthLocator
ax[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b %Y"))
ax[0].set(xlabel=None, ylabel="Price")  # Set title and labels for axes

df[["Adj Close"]].plot(ax=ax[1], kind="line", style="-", color="blue", stacked=False, rot=90)
ax[1].set_axisbelow(True)  # To put plot grid below plots
ax[1].yaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax[1].xaxis.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())  # specify a MonthLocator
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b %Y"))
ax[1].set(xlabel="Time", ylabel="Price")  # Set title and labels for axes

fig.savefig("0P0000UL8U.L.png", bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank for any help in advance.

Comment: For the random years, I could not reproduce the issue (it shows correctly on my PC). Maybe check that your system time is synced.

Comment: Thanks for the solution for the x-axis of the top plot. Concerning the dates, what do you mean by "system time synced"?

Comment: Python gives me the following warning as well:
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The epoch2num function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
  base = dates.epoch2num(dt.asi8 / 1.0e9)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I was referring to the system time (OS calendar/clock) to be synced to the real time (though I doubt that would not be true in most cases). In my case it worked with Matplotlib 3.1.2, so you might consider that as well

Comment: Calendar system seem synced alright.

Could dit be that the date series is not continuous (i.e. there are gaps in the days)? Btw, that's why it would be important to get the code right, rather than using `df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`...

Answer (score 1):

To remove the x-Axis labels from the top graph, you can add the following line:

`ax[0].tick_params(labelbottom=False)`

before `ax[0].set(xlabel=None, ylabel="Price")`

Answer (score 0):

It's not your fault. Python 3 is very far from stable yet. That's why hardcore developers still prefer Python 2. This time matplotlib devs screwed dates handling. They even have a number of corresponding bugs (#18010, #17983, #34850).
Meantime you can downgrade matplotlib to v 3.2.2, it's working perfectly and wait if devs repair the bug.